# Stripe Payment on user behalf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, user-controls, payment-gateway, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I am using Stripe for payments. I want to transfer funds to other
Stripe users. My account is not in USA.

```
   begin
      Stripe::Charge.create(
        :amount => amount_in_cents(amount),
        :currency => DEFAULT_CURRENCY,
        :customer => client.payment_token,
        :description => session_or_purchase.payment_description
      )
    rescue Stripe::CardError, Stripe::InvalidRequestError, Stripe::APIConnectionError, Stripe::StripeError  => e
      body = e.json_body
      err  = body[:error]
      return err
    rescue => e
      error = {type: 'Unknown', message: 'Some thing else happened ', param: ''}
    end
```

Is there any way, I can charge on my customer on other users behalf? I have to pass the application API keys on every transaction, and all payment go to application account, but I want to transfer an amount to the user and deduct some amount: i.e. application charges to my app account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stripe gives you a way to do that using Stripe connect. Check [this](https://stripe.com/docs/connect) for the reference.

Comment: While this might be an answer to the question, links decay and stack overflow is meant to be an endpoint, if you could include the relevant parts of the docs in here to prevent the answer from being flagged as link only.

Comment: You could add screenshots of the flow + it's different steps here

Comment: Definately add more info here. While that link is valid, its not an answer